# How to change a template exported from overleaf

Tags: titles, templates, overleaf

I am doing my project,for that I import a template from overleaf,I want to change the institute name
and doctor of philosophy ,for that what I need to do, here I attach a screenshot which make things more clear...please help me[image]

Comment: Have a look inside `A_title → A01_title.tex` there you can change `\department{AEROSPACE ENGINEERING}` and then line 216 of `iitmdiss.cls` `{\bf \large \MakeUppercase{Doctor of Philosophy}} \par`. That should do it.

Comment: Hello Robin! Tom from Overleaf Support Team here. From what you posted here, I'm afraid it's impossible to crystal-ball what's the project's setup and how to solve your issue. But you can reach me on Overleaf support email address and we can see what's going on there.

Also, as this question stands, I'm afraid it's not answerable on this site; to allow other users to answer the question, you would have to provide the code, see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/11002 for some best practices on how to do this.

Comment: I actually mean changing "Department of Indian Institute of Technology Madras " to my Institute... Iam able to change doctor of philosophy as you suggested @ phil-elkabat